# Python. How to get start and end date from list of dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, odoo-8

[Python. How to get start and end date from list of dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbcw8.jpg)

Comment: SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your homework. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code. Do not post links to offsite resources, they die too fast.

Answer (score 1):

Datetimes have built in sorting.

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime(1990, 1, 1)
b = datetime(2000, 1, 1)

min(a, b) 
>>datetime(1990,1,1)
```